# Brunch not picking up vendor CSS as expected

Tags: css, brunch

I'm trying to use [Pure.css](http://purecss.io/) in my application. I've installed it using npm and have my `brunch-config.js` configured like so:

```
stylesheets: {
  joinTo: {
    'app.css': /^app/,
    'vendor.css': /^(?!app)/
  }
}
```

I expect `vendor.css` to be generated at this point, but it's not. However, if in my JavaScript, I say `require('purecss');`, *then* I get `vendor.css` generated...but I also get the JavaScript error `Cannot find module 'purecss' from '<filename>'`. I've also tried various permutations of `@import 'purecss'` in my CSS without success.

How does one consume vendor CSS from npm modules?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `npm` [config section](http://brunch.io/docs/config#-npm-), for example when I wanted to include `node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css` I had to put the following in my `brunch-config.js`:

```
npm: {
  styles: {
    bootstrap: ['dist/css/bootstrap.css']
  }
}
```

That, combined with your section in `files` makes it write bootstrap's css into `vendor.css`.

---

Full `brunch-config.js` that works for me:

```
module.exports = {
  files: {
    javascripts: {
      joinTo: {
        'app.js': /^app/,
        'vendor.js': /^(?!app)/
      }
    },
    stylesheets: {
      joinTo: {
        'app.css': /^app/,
        'vendor.css': /^(?!app)/
      }
    }
  },

  plugins: {
    babel: { presets: ['es2015'] }
  },

  npm: {
    styles: {
      bootstrap: ['dist/css/bootstrap.css']
    }
  }
};
```